# Перевести миллисекунды в дни часы: минуты: секунды в JasperReports

Tags: java, jasperreports, simpledateformat

В любом ЯП это делается легко и просто делением и делением с остатком. НО Jasper Reports имеет свой xml формат, в котором как я понял нельзя производить деление с остатком. Поэтому стандартные средства не подходят. Мне необходимо перевести определенное кол-во миллисекунд в дни, часы, минуты и секунды. Было бы здорово, если бы вы подсказали какой нибудь dateFormatter на java, который поможет преобразовать миллисекунды. Миллисекунды хранятся в переменной типа Long.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, для этого отлично подходит класс DurationFormatUtils

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DurationFormatUtils.formatPeriod($F{startDate}.getTime(), $F{endDate}.getTime(), "dd'd' HH':'mm", true, $P{REPORT_TIME_ZONE})
```